# Signin a user automatically given password and username without clicking on a button using Oauth? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

Sorry the title is a little bit long.
So I have a twitter account and a twitter app, I want my account to be able to use "@name your information has been updated" once a particular user's information on my app is changed, in order to do
this, I need to get an access token for my own account automatically. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a registered app, you can few an access token and secret pair for the account that registered the application (presumably yours).  You can use that pair, along with the app's consumer key/secret to make your oauth calls.

You can find your token by going into your App's settings and then selecting My Access Token on the right.